# Don't send invisible elements in form with post method using serialize() jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have rows in a form in html with bootstrap 4. 1 is visible and 2 are hidden.

The last column of each row is dynamic (it is generated with jquery). However, when I send via POST using serialize () in Jquery the 3 rows are sent with their elements, I need to send only the visible rows. Can you help me by indicating that I am doing wrong? Invisible elements are not supposed to be sent in the form. Why here?

HTML (Notice that #block2 and #block3 are containers with class d-none):

```html
<div class="bloques">
   <div class="row bloque-filtros" id="bloque1">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-control-wrap">
               <select class="form-select form-control form-control-xl parametro" name="parametro1" data-ui="xl" data-id="1" required="">
                  <option value="#">Selecciona una opción</option>
                  <option value="1">Edad</option>
                  <option value="2">Sexo</option>
                  <option value="3">Estado / Provincia</option>
                  <option value="4">Salario deseado</option>
                  <option value="5">Categoría</option>
                  <option value="6">Estado civil</option>
                  <option value="7">Disponibilidad</option>
                  <option value="8">Nivel de estudio</option>
               </select>
               <label class="form-label-outlined" for="outlined-select">Filtro<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-control-wrap">
               <select class="form-select form-control form-control-xl operador" name="operador1" data-ui="xl" required="">
                  <option value="#">Selecciona una opción</option>
                  <option value="1">Mayor que > </option>
                  <option value="2">< Menor que </option>
                  <option value="3">Igual que = </option>
                  <option value="5">Difrente que != </option>
               </select>
               <label class="form-label-outlined" for="outlined-select">Operador lógico<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-control-wrap divvalue1">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class="row bloque-filtros d-none" id="bloque2">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-control-wrap">
               <select class="form-select form-control form-control-xl parametro" name="parametro2" data-ui="xl" data-id="2" required="">
                  <option value="#">Selecciona una opción</option>
                  <option value="1">Edad</option>
                  <option value="2">Sexo</option>
                  <option value="3">Estado / Provincia</option>
                  <option value="4">Salario deseado</option>
                  <option value="5">Categoría</option>
                  <option value="6">Estado civil</option>
                  <option value="7">Disponibilidad</option>
                  <option value="8">Nivel de estudio</option>
               </select>
               <label class="form-label-outlined" for="outlined-select">Filtro<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-control-wrap">
               <select class="form-select form-control form-control-xl operador" name="operador2" data-ui="xl" required="">
                  <option value="#">Selecciona una opción</option>
                  <option value="1">Mayor que > </option>
                  <option value="2">< Menor que </option>
                  <option value="3">Igual que = </option>
                  <option value="5">Difrente que != </option>
               </select>
               <label class="form-label-outlined" for="outlined-select">Operador lógico<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-control-wrap divvalue2">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class="row bloque-filtros d-none" id="bloque3">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-control-wrap">
               <select class="form-select form-control form-control-xl parametro" name="parametro3" data-ui="xl" data-id="3" required="">
                  <option value="#">Selecciona una opción</option>
                  <option value="1">Edad</option>
                  <option value="2">Sexo</option>
                  <option value="3">Estado / Provincia</option>
                  <option value="4">Salario deseado</option>
                  <option value="5">Categoría</option>
                  <option value="6">Estado civil</option>
                  <option value="7">Disponibilidad</option>
                  <option value="8">Nivel de estudio</option>
               </select>
               <label class="form-label-outlined" for="outlined-select">Filtro<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-control-wrap">
               <select class="form-select form-control form-control-xl operador" name="operador3" data-ui="xl" required="">
                  <option value="#">Selecciona una opción</option>
                  <option value="1">Mayor que > </option>
                  <option value="2">< Menor que </option>
                  <option value="3">Igual que = </option>
                  <option value="5">Difrente que != </option>
               </select>
               <label class="form-label-outlined" for="outlined-select">Operador lógico<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-control-wrap divvalue3">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <br>
   <input class="btn btn-gray btn-fw" id="addBloque" value="Nuevo filtro">
</div>
```

JQuery:

```js
$('#formCrearOferta').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var serialized = form.serialize();
    if (!form.valid()) return false;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url+'ajax.php',
        data: serialized,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#loading').removeClass('d-none');
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $('#loading').addClass('d-none');
                console.log(response);
            },
    });
});
```

Result in php:
[image]

**Edit1**:
I have a hidden field in the form that if I need to submit

```html
<input type="hidden" id="crearOferta" name="crearOferta" >
```

**Edit2**.

Example, What I need to receive (Without the hidden divs):
[image]

How to prevent hidden items from being sent?
Thank you.

Comment: Could you make a more minimal example? You don't need the full form to show the behavior.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev What are you talking about?

Comment: You would need to use jQuery to physically remove the html from the page instead of hiding with CSS. So like, $(“.d-none select”).remove(); just before you serialize

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2   Controls hidden with CSS are still able to be sent.

Comment: If you do not want them to be sent remove their name attribute or set them disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use :not(:hidden) selector instead of form to do the trick,
so remove this

```
var form = $(this);
    var serialized = form.serialize();
```

and replace it with

```
var form = $(this).find(":input:not(:hidden)").serializeArray();
```

so you will get only the shown input results

Comment: Your answer works very well, the problem is that I have a hidden field that I do need to send. I have updated my post, (I apologize). You find it as "Edit1".

Comment: you can simply add any additional attr to all hidden ( NOT INCLUDED IN SERIALIZED DATA ) and use it instead of :hidden, eg.
`<input type="hidden" id="NotPosted" data="Exclude" name="NotPosted" >
<input type="hidden" id="crearOferta" name="crearOferta" >
var form = $(this).find(":input:not([data='exclude'])").serializeArray();`

Comment: It worked for me thank you very much. Do you know why input submits are not sent?

Comment: as i see you are using `url+` << which is undefined variable,
you need to define the `url` variable first

Answer (score 1):

One simple trick is to wrap the hidden ones in a disabled `<fieldset>`.

Disabling a fieldset disables all form controls within it

```js
const $form = $('#demo-form');

console.log('Before disable:', $form.serialize())

$('.d-none').wrap('<fieldset disabled>');// OR wrapInner()

console.log('After disable:', $form.serialize())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="demo-form">
<div class="bloques">
   <div class="row bloque-filtros" id="bloque1">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-control-wrap">
               <select class="form-select form-control form-control-xl parametro" name="parametro1" data-ui="xl" data-id="1" required="">
                  <option value="#">Selecciona una opción</option>
                  <option value="1">Edad</option>
                  <option value="2">Sexo</option>
                  <option value="3" selected>Estado / Provincia</option>
                  <option value="4">Salario deseado</option>
                  <option value="5">Categoría</option>
                  <option value="6">Estado civil</option>
                  <option value="7">Disponibilidad</option>
                  <option value="8">Nivel de estudio</option>
               </select>
               <label class="form-label-outlined" for="outlined-select">Filtro<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-control-wrap">
               <select class="form-select form-control form-control-xl operador" name="operador1" data-ui="xl" required="">
                  <option value="#">Selecciona una opción</option>
                  <option value="1">Mayor que > </option>
                  <option value="2"  selected>< Menor que </option>
                  <option value="3">Igual que = </option>
                  <option value="5">Difrente que != </option>
               </select>
               <label class="form-label-outlined" for="outlined-select">Operador lógico<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-control-wrap divvalue1">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class="row bloque-filtros d-none" id="bloque2">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-control-wrap">
               <select class="form-select form-control form-control-xl parametro" name="parametro2" data-ui="xl" data-id="2" required="">
                  <option value="#">Selecciona una opción</option>
                  <option value="1">Edad</option>
                  <option value="2">Sexo</option>
                  <option value="3">Estado / Provincia</option>
                  <option value="4">Salario deseado</option>
                  <option value="5" selected>Categoría</option>
                  <option value="6">Estado civil</option>
                  <option value="7">Disponibilidad</option>
                  <option value="8">Nivel de estudio</option>
               </select>
               <label class="form-label-outlined" for="outlined-select">Filtro<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-control-wrap">
               <select class="form-select form-control form-control-xl operador" name="operador2" data-ui="xl" required="">
                  <option value="#">Selecciona una opción</option>
                  <option value="1">Mayor que > </option>
                  <option value="2"  selected>< Menor que </option>
                  <option value="3">Igual que = </option>
                  <option value="5">Difrente que != </option>
               </select>
               <label class="form-label-outlined" for="outlined-select">Operador lógico<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-control-wrap divvalue2">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class="row bloque-filtros d-none" id="bloque3">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-control-wrap">
               <select class="form-select form-control form-control-xl parametro" name="parametro3" data-ui="xl" data-id="3" required="">
                  <option value="#">Selecciona una opción</option>
                  <option value="1">Edad</option>
                  <option value="2">Sexo</option>
                  <option value="3">Estado / Provincia</option>
                  <option value="4">Salario deseado</option>
                  <option value="5">Categoría</option>
                  <option value="6" selected>Estado civil</option>
                  <option value="7">Disponibilidad</option>
                  <option value="8">Nivel de estudio</option>
               </select>
               <label class="form-label-outlined" for="outlined-select">Filtro<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-control-wrap">
               <select class="form-select form-control form-control-xl operador" name="operador3" data-ui="xl" required="">
                  <option value="#">Selecciona una opción</option>
                  <option value="1">Mayor que > </option>
                  <option value="2">< Menor que </option>
                  <option value="3"  selected>Igual que = </option>
                  <option value="5">Difrente que != </option>
               </select>
               <label class="form-label-outlined" for="outlined-select">Operador lógico<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-control-wrap divvalue3">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <br>
   <input class="btn btn-gray btn-fw" id="addBloque" value="Nuevo filtro">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your answer works very well, the problem is that I have a hidden field that I do need to send. I have updated my post, (I apologize). You find it as "Edit1".

Comment: So just make sure that hidden field is not inside the class that gets hidden and it won;t get disabled

Answer (score 0):

You can choose fields manually:

```
var serialized = JSON.stringify({ 
    "crearOferta": $("#crearOferta").text(),
    "parametro1": $("select[name='parametro1']").val(),
    "operador2": $("select[name='operador2']").val(),
});
```